# Select option is not returning what I choose

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a select options drop down where I can choose between 5sec and 10sec.Wehn I choose 5sec it should return an alert message in 5 sec and when I choose 10sec it should return an alert message in 10 sec. The problem is that when I choose 5sec it returns first message in 5 sec and after it returns automatically another message in 10 sec.It should only return message acording what I choose in drop down. Any ide how I can fix this?
my code:

```
<select id="setTimer">
     <option value="5sec">5sec</option>
     <option value="10sec">10sec</option>
     <option value="15sec">15sec</option>
 </select>

var opt = $("#setTimer");
setInterval(function fiveSec() { alert("5sec") }, 5000);
setInterval(function tenSec() { alert("10sec") }, 10000);

$(document).ready(function () {
  if (opt.text == "5sec") {
     fiveSec();
  }
  if (opt.text == "10sec") {
     tenSec();
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#setTimer").change(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "5sec") {
     setTimeout(function(){alert("5sec")}, 5000)
  }
  else if ($(this).text() == "10sec") {
     setTimeout(function(){alert("10sec")}, 10000)
  } 
 });
});
```

Explanation: this waits for the page to load, then grabs your select input and assigns "change" event to it. When it is changed, i.e. the user make a selection, it checks whether the selection is "5sec" or "10sec" and then sets a timeout accordingly. I haven't tried it myself but it should work.

Note that `setInterval` will execute every X number of seconds, whereas `setTimeout` will execute only once.

Comment: I tried but returns nothing.

Comment: By "returns nothing" you mean no pop up? You need to debug by putting alerts in various places.

Comment: Yes, no pop up. Ok i'll try that. thx

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need setInterval. This should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#setTimer").change(function() {
    alert($(this).text())
 });
});
```